# Android App will not run, null point exception at MainActivity

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter, logcat

I have created an app in which i use an ArrayAdapter to load values of row items into a listview, but after trying to run the app on my virtual device i am presented with the following error log:

My code for my MainActivity: follows the error log

```
07-08 02:11:07.077: D/AndroidRuntime(995): Shutting down VM
07-08 02:11:07.107: W/dalvikvm(995): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception                          
(group=0x41465700)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to       
instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.deenbuddy/com.example.deenbuddy.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at   
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at   
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at   
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at    
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
Method)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at 
android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at 
android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at com.example.deenbuddy.MainActivity.<init>
(MainActivity.java:23)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native 
Method)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at  
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at   
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  at    
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
07-08 02:11:07.146: E/AndroidRuntime(995):  ... 11 more

package com.example.deenbuddy;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.example.deenbuddy.RowItem;
import com.example.deenbuddy.CListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

//Arrays for RowItem values

final String[] uname = new String[] {getResources().getString(R.string.social),getResources().getString(R.string.social),getResources().getString(R.string.social)};

final String[] ustatus = new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.temp_ustatus0),getResources().getString(R.string.temp_ustat    us0),getResources().getString(R.string.temp_ustatus0)};
final Integer[] upic = new Integer[]{R.drawable.tig0,R.drawable.tig0,R.drawable.tig0};

//ListView and RowItem for ListView
ListView listview;
List<RowItem> rowItem;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//News Buttons 
ImageView newsb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news1);
ImageView newsb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news2);
ImageView newsb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news3);
ImageView newsb4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.news4);

//Feature Buttons
ImageView featb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat1);
ImageView featb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat2);
ImageView featb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat3);
ImageView featb4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.feat4);

//OnClicks for news
newsb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
    }
});

newsb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
    }
});

newsb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
    }
});

newsb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
    }
});

//OnClicks for feat
featb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
    }
});

featb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
    }
});

featb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
    }
});

featb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.newstitle);
    }
});

rowItem = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
for(int x = 0; x < uname.length; x++)
{
    RowItem item = new RowItem(upic[x], uname[x], ustatus[x]);
    rowItem.add(item);
}

listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sfeed);
ArrayAdapter<RowItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RowItem>     
(this,R.layout.sfeed_list,rowItem);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
listview.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener)this);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
} 



}
```

I know this is a lot to read through but perhaps someone could help me understand what my problem is without having to read the whole log...any and all help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance for reading and replying.

Comment: Post `MainActivity` code....

Comment: can you please update your code without code we are not able to help you.

Comment: The error, according to the messages above is on line 23 of MainActivity... That's where you/we will need to look (and before and after it... errors aren't always just about the line it's on, but often those preceeding.)

Comment: I think you have tried access `context` sooner as its initialized

Comment: Please upload your activity code to know the exact issue.

Comment: post your listadapter calling line or post your mainactivity code

Comment: Hello and thank you for your replies, I have posted my MainActivity code as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check these are all present in your code

```
public class youractivityname extends activity{

Context context;
@override
public void Oncreate(Bundle savedInstancestate)
{
super.oncreate(savedInstacestate);
context=this;

//........yourcode

yourlistview.this.runOnUiThread(new runnable){

@override
public void run()
{
//youradapter calling with context parameter along with required parameters 
yourlistview.setadapter(yourlistadapetObject);
}

});
}
}
```

then run and let me inform

Comment: sorry this did not seem to work, and causes other errors, I have replied with an answer that include my code...please take a look at it.  Thank you.

Comment: put these lines your code into runOnUiThread it will work                                listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sfeed);
ArrayAdapter<RowItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RowItem>     
(this,R.layout.sfeed_list,rowItem);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);      once you achieve let me inform

Comment: I will try your way for extra credit but i have recently solved the problem by using Integer class to initiate my arrays and to pass to the adapter, which i also custom made.  Thank you so much for your help, i will explore your techniques as well!